# Array splice is not working in this method what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am trying to insert new item in the following position. The point is that concat() works fine but when I use slice or splice it doesn't. And even doesn't show any error just shows empty screen.

```
 getItems() {
      const item2 = {
        name: '...',
        description: '...',
        id: '...',
      }
      let items = { ...this.items }
      
        return Object.keys(items)
          .map(id => ({
            ...items[id],
            id,
          }))
          .splice(2, 0, item2)
      ...
}
```

Here is how it looks like. Why concat works fine but not slice or splice? And how can I push that item in my desired position on other way if these methods will not work?

Comment: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array of the deleted items and otherwise mutates the array in place.

Comment: Yes I know that and I need to return the modified array. Slice is also not working. Only concat works

Comment: Then don't return the result of `splice` as you do now - instead assign to a variable, splice, then return that.

Comment: Anyway doesn't work

Comment: It's fun that only concat works,

Comment: Is there any other method e.g. inside lodash that can solve this?

Comment: `concat` only works if you *directly* return the result of it. As I said, if you *don't* do that, then you can use `splice`

Comment: @VLAZ is telling you how to make it work. Assign the result of `Object.keys().map()` to a variable. Call splice on it. Return the variable.

Comment: I did as you said and the result is the same.

Comment: what is the schema for `this.items`? and what is the expected output and what is the latest codes you tried? could you add them into the question?

Comment: I am using vuejs, above mentioned item2 like objects are included inside that items. In console.log it shows the array but on the screen it's empty but when I put concat instead it shows the results

Comment: console.log returns empty array.

Comment: Do you really want to splice at start index of 2 or should it be adding new elements every time you call it? Can you provide more info?

Comment: It's not dynamic array. Later will not be added new items.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I correctly understand what you're trying to do, you have two choices:

1. Inside `getItems`, make a new array, modify the new array to insert the value, return the new array.
2. Inside `getItems`, declare a new array in one line and return that.

Example for option 1:

```
getItems() {
  const item2 = {
    name: '...',
    description: '...',
    id: '...',
  }

  let items = { ...this.items }
      
  const resultArray = Object.keys(items)
    .map(id => ({
      ...items[id],
      id,
    }))

  resultArray.splice(2, 0, item2) // This does **not** return the right value, it only modifies resultArray to become the value you want.
  return resultArray // Instead we return resultArray on a new line.
}
```

And for option 2:

```
getItems() {
  const item2 = {
    name: '...',
    description: '...',
    id: '...',
  }

  let items = { ...this.items }
      
  const resultArray = Object.keys(items)
    .map(id => ({
      ...items[id],
      id,
    }))

  return [ ...resultArray.slice(0, 2), item2, ...resultArray.slice(2) ]
}
```

To answer your question about why `concat()` works but not `slice()` or `splice()`: `concat()` returns a new array with the elements added. `slice()` can't be used to make an array with items added. `splice()` does two different things at once: it modifies an array to remove or insert items, *and* it returns a new array that contains only what was removed.

The second example is quite similar to using `concat()` to solve the problem: it is equivalent to `return [].concat(resultArray.slice(0, 2), [item2], resultArray.slice(2))`.